# My Apple ID is locked but it also says it doesn't exist

Tags: apple-id, password, accounts

I’ve been trying to get my Apple ID unlocked, but every time I type it in at https://iforgot.apple.com, it says that there is no Apple ID associated with that email address.

How can I unlock my Apple ID?

Comment: Have you tried going to https://iforgot.apple.com?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing until now. Every time I type in my account, it keeps saying that this Apple ID does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Head on to [Find Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid#!&section=appleid). Type in your name and email address to figure out if your actual Apple ID may be different from the email address you’ve been typing in.

If you’re unable to get your Apple ID back, Apple provides [a few more steps](https://support.apple.com/HT201354) you might try to recover your Apple ID if the one you’re trying isn’t the right one.

If everything else fails, you’ll need to contact [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com) directly. Click through the links for Apple ID and pick the contact option that best suits you.